# Replace a column value based on max count of values in a groupby scenario pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],'sid':['X','Y','X','Z','X','Y','X','Y','Z'], 'cl':[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]})
df
    id  sid cl
0   1   X   0
1   2   Y   1
2   3   X   1
3   4   Z   0
4   5   X   0
5   6   Y   1
6   7   X   0
7   8   Y   0
8   9   Z   1
```

What i want to do is first group by 'sid' and take count of 'cl' values, the cl values having the max count should be the value for all the rows in that group.

So for the data frame df, sid ='X', the cl values are 0,1,0,0 . As we can see that 0 is the most frequent occuring value, so all cl values under the sid "X", should be updated to 0, similarly for 'Y' it should be 1 and for 'Z' both 0 and 1 occur once and hence any of the 1 value can be chosen.

The resulting data frame should look like:

```
    id  sid cl cl_new
0   1   X   0   0
1   2   Y   1   1
2   3   X   1   0
3   4   Z   0   0
4   5   X   0   0
5   6   Y   1   1
6   7   X   0   0
7   8   Y   0   1 
8   9   Z   1   0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `groupby.transform` + [`Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html#pandas-series-mode):

```py
df["cl_new"] = df.groupby("sid")["cl"].transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id sid  cl  cl_new
0   1   X   0       0
1   2   Y   1       1
2   3   X   1       0
3   4   Z   0       0
4   5   X   0       0
5   6   Y   1       1
6   7   X   0       0
7   8   Y   0       1
8   9   Z   1       0
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by `sid` and count values per group and return the index of the max occurences then merge to you original dataframe:

```
df['cl_new'] = df.groupby('sid')['cl'].transform(lambda x: x.value_counts().idxmax())
```

```
>>> df
   id sid  cl  cl_new
0   1   X   0       0
1   2   Y   1       1
2   3   X   1       0
3   4   Z   0       0
4   5   X   0       0
5   6   Y   1       1
6   7   X   0       0
7   8   Y   0       1
8   9   Z   1       0
```